# How do I link a company's Google Plus site to the company's Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-plus

Is there any way by which I might link a company's Google Plus site to its Analytics properties? The client wants to track traffic on the G+ site via Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at http://online-behavior.com/analytics/googleplus which discussed specific techniques to be able to track Google+ event (such as +1 clicks) through your Google Analytics account.